# Fitting single exponential decay error python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, exponential

I have two arrays which would lead to a plot of df_intensity_01 vs df_time.

```
df_time
[[  0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170
  180 190 200 210 220 230 240 250 260 270 280 290 300 310 320 330 340 350
  360 370 380 390 400 410 420 430 440 450 460 470 480 490 500 510 520 530
  540 550 560 570 580 590 600 610 620 630 640 650 660 670 680 690 700 710
  720 730 740 750 760 770 780 790 800]]

df_intensity_01
[1.         0.98666909 0.935487   0.91008815 0.86347009 0.81356788
 0.79591582 0.78624289 0.76503846 0.75105705 0.72333501 0.67815733
 0.69481674 0.68321344 0.66108185 0.65859392 0.64047511 0.63100282
 0.63605049 0.6248548  0.60341172 0.57538132 0.57952294 0.57901395
 0.56353725 0.56164702 0.55901125 0.54833934 0.53271058 0.52880127
 0.52268282 0.51111965 0.5067436  0.49988595 0.49689326 0.48888879
 0.48247889 0.4790469  0.47320723 0.46156169 0.45921527 0.4592913
 0.45104607 0.44445031 0.44618426 0.43893589 0.42988811 0.42887013
 0.42842872 0.41952032 0.41286965 0.41392143 0.41175663 0.40432874
 0.39645523 0.39813004 0.38932936 0.38264912 0.38094263 0.3855869
 0.38378537 0.37570065 0.37573022 0.37550635 0.36941113 0.36502241
 0.36607629 0.36624103 0.36163477 0.35550154 0.35627875 0.35421111
 0.34858053 0.34767026 0.34967665 0.34818347 0.34007975 0.34139552
 0.34017057 0.33732993 0.33320098]
```

I am trying to fit the data to a single exponential decay function where I have provided the initial coefficients of the fit.

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
xdata = df_time
guess=[1,0.001,0]
ydata = df_intensity
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata,p0=guess)
popt

plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',
         label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

I get an error which I really dont know how to solve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-97bcc77fc6c7> in <module>
      5 ydata = df_intensity
      6 plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
----> 7 popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata,p0=guess)
      8 popt
      9 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    749         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    750         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 751         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    752         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    753         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    392         with _MINPACK_LOCK:
    393             retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
--> 394                                      gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    395     else:
    396         if col_deriv:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need both your inputs to both be 1D arrays (only one set of braces: `[ ]`). Currently it looks like `df_time` is a 2D array, which appears to be the source of the error you posted.

Then, when you plot the data, remember that you need to evaluate the function *for each value of `x`*, so that your `x` and `y` arrays are the same length. You can do this with a list comprehension, remembering to convert your `x` values to `float` so you can pass them to your function:

```
plt.plot(xdata, [func(float(x), *popt) for x in xdata], 'r-',
         label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
```

The whole working code looks like this:

```
df_time = ['0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100',
           '110', '120', '130', '140', '150', '160', '170', '180', '190', '200',
           '210', '220', '230', '240', '250', '260', '270', '280', '290', '300',
           '310', '320', '330', '340', '350', '360', '370', '380', '390', '400',
           '410', '420', '430', '440', '450', '460', '470', '480', '490', '500',
           '510', '520', '530', '540', '550', '560', '570', '580', '590', '600',
           '610', '620', '630', '640', '650', '660', '670', '680', '690', '700',
           '710', '720', '730', '740', '750', '760', '770', '780', '790', '800']

df_intensity = ['1.', '0.98666909', '0.935487', '0.91008815', '0.86347009', '0.81356788',
                '0.79591582', '0.78624289', '0.76503846', '0.75105705', '0.72333501', '0.67815733',
                '0.69481674', '0.68321344', '0.66108185', '0.65859392', '0.64047511', '0.63100282',
                '0.63605049', '0.6248548', '0.60341172', '0.57538132', '0.57952294', '0.57901395',
                '0.56353725', '0.56164702', '0.55901125', '0.54833934', '0.53271058', '0.52880127',
                '0.52268282', '0.51111965', '0.5067436', '0.49988595', '0.49689326', '0.48888879',
                '0.48247889', '0.4790469', '0.47320723', '0.46156169', '0.45921527', '0.4592913',
                '0.45104607', '0.44445031', '0.44618426', '0.43893589', '0.42988811', '0.42887013',
                '0.42842872', '0.41952032', '0.41286965', '0.41392143', '0.41175663', '0.40432874',
                '0.39645523', '0.39813004', '0.38932936', '0.38264912', '0.38094263', '0.3855869',
                '0.38378537', '0.37570065', '0.37573022', '0.37550635', '0.36941113', '0.36502241',
                '0.36607629', '0.36624103', '0.36163477', '0.35550154', '0.35627875', '0.35421111',
                '0.34858053', '0.34767026', '0.34967665', '0.34818347', '0.34007975', '0.34139552',
                '0.34017057', '0.33732993', '0.33320098']

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = [float(x) for x in df_time]
guess=[1,0.001,0]
ydata = df_intensity
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata,p0=guess)

fig = plt.figure()  # created a 2nd figure for 2nd plot

plt.plot(xdata, [func(float(x), *popt) for x in xdata], 'r-',
         label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y');
```